# Explicit form of Meijer G-function $G_{1,3}^{3,0}$

Tags: special-functions

Please, can the following Meijer G-function

$$G_{1,3}^{3,0}\left(a^2\Bigg|
    \begin{array}{c}
    n+2 \\
    -\dfrac{1}{2},1,\dfrac{3}{2} \\
    \end{array}
    \right)$$

```
MeijerG[{{},{2+n}},{{-(1/2),1,3/2},{}},a^2]
```

be expressed more explicitly in terms of other special functions, but involving no infinite integrals?

$a\;$ is positive real number and $\;n=0,1,2\;$ is an integer.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, this result comes from an integral, this is the MA syntax `MeijerG[{{},{2+n}},{{-(1/2),1,3/2},{}},a^2]`

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, it comes from this integral $\frac{a^2\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\left (x^2 - 1 \right)^{n + \frac{3}{2}}\exp(-a x)}{x^{2 n + 1}}\, dx} {K_2(a)} $ `(a^2/BesselK[2,a]) Integrate[(x^2-1)^(n+(3/2))/x^(2n+1) Exp[-a x],{x,1,Infinity}]`

Comment: I don't think anything is known. There are [known formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/03/01/05/03/) for $G^{3,0}_{1,3}$ but none of them match your specific case.

Comment: @K.defaoite, yes but the issue is that `b3-b1 = 3/2-(-1/2) = 2` is an integer in my expression, which is excluded from the formula on the functions page.

Comment: Precisely why I said "none of them match your specific case".